# This demo works 4 out of 5 times, why is it giving me an error sometimes?

Tags: java, applet, awt, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I am practicing rendering and drawing graphics, I can't seem to find out why eclipse gives me an error around 1/5 of the time.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at game.StartingPoint.run(StartingPoint.java:74)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is it a problem with my thread? How can I fix this?

Here is my source code.

**StartingPoint.java**:

```
package game;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class StartingPoint extends Applet implements Runnable {

    Image i;
    Graphics doubleG;
    Ball b1;
    Ball b2;

    public StartingPoint() {

    }

    @Override
    public void init() {

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {

        setSize(480, 360);

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

        b1 = new Ball(40, 40);
        b2 = new Ball(70, 200);

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {

        if (i == null) {
            i = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            doubleG = i.getGraphics();
        }
        doubleG.setColor(getBackground());
        doubleG.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        doubleG.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(doubleG);

        g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        b1.paint(g);
        b2.paint(g);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            b1.update(this);
            b2.update(this);

            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.print("Error");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Ball.java**:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ball {
    double gravity = 15.0;
    double energyLoss = .65;
    double outsideEnergy = .95;
    double dt = .25;
    double xFriction = .9;
    int x = 40;
    int y = 40;
    double dx = 7.0;
    double dy = 0.0;
    int radius = 20;

    public Ball() {

    }

    public Ball(int x, int y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

    }

    public void update(StartingPoint sp) {
        if (x <= 0 | x >= sp.getWidth()) {
            dx = -dx;
        }

        if (y > sp.getHeight() - radius - 1) {
            y = sp.getHeight() - radius - 1;
            dy *= energyLoss;
            dy = -dy;
            dx *= outsideEnergy;
            } else {
            // velocity
            dy = dy + gravity * dt;
            // d=viT + 1/2(a)t^2
            y += dy * dt + .5 * gravity * dt * dt;

        }

        x += dx;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);

    }
}
```

Comment: The keywords are `Thread` and `null`.

Comment: The odds speak heavily in favor of something being "not thread safe".

Comment: Not truly answering your question, but I feel it should be mentioned. You seem to understand some basic physic principles and apply them correctly here, so why not utilize vectors? It will help sort out the functions a bit more in terms of acceleration. You create a constant gravity vector and can apply it continuously. Just something to consider :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();

b1 = new Ball(40, 40);
b2 = new Ball(70, 200);
```

You are initializing your variables after your thread starts.  Sometimes the thread uses them before they are actually initialized, sometimes they get initialized first.  Move them before the `start()` call:

```
b1 = new Ball(40, 40);
b2 = new Ball(70, 200);

Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's your problem:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();

b1 = new Ball(40, 40);
b2 = new Ball(70, 200);
```

You need to set `b1` and `b2` before calling `thread.start()` -- the call to `start` calls your `run` method in a new thread, and there's a chance the run method could be called before these variables are itinitialized, leading to your NullPointerException.

---

**EDIT:**

To troubleshoot threading issues, it's useful to consider a conceptual model where the JVM is only capable of executing one line of code at a time, and different lines of code from different threads could be interleaved in any order, as long as lines of code from any one thread get executed in the correct order. With modern CPU architectures that isn't actually the case, but just pretend...

When you encounter problems in multithreaded code, your goal is to find a way of interleaving the operations that reproduces your problem. For instance:

```
     Thread 1                              Thread2
 1   b1 = null; (implicit in constructor)
 2   b2 = null; (implicit in constructor)
 3   Thread thread = new Thread(this)
 4   thread.start();
 5   b1 = new Ball(40, 40);
 6                                         b1.update(this); (OK because b1 is initialized)
 7                                         b2.update(this); (NPE - b2 is not initialize)
 8   b2 = new Ball(70, 200);
```

Your goal then becomes to either rearrange lines within the same thread to ensure the problematic sequence never happens, or using language constructs such as `synchronized` blocks or higher-level locks to restrict the ways in which instructions from different threads can interleave.

Answer (score 3):

This error is telling you that b1 or b2  (or both) are not initialized (ie, are null)

Why this is the case will require a few minutes of analysis, but that's the immediate issue.

EDIT: see Alex and Chancea's posts.